# How to iterate from current index over a list and update the next element number to previous deleted index element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

```
    Code:
list1 = ["B1": "Aman"; "B2": "Roshni"; "B3": "Utkarsh"; "B4": "Kritika"; "B5": "Mansi"; "B6": "Dimple"]
    data=B3
for i, d in enumerate(list1):
if data in d.keys():
           del dict1[i]
    print(list1)
          
list1 = ["B1": "Aman"; "B2": "Roshni"; "B4": "Kritika"; "B5": "Mansi"; "B6": "Dimple"]
```

After this, the lists become as above.I want to update lists to
list1 = ["B1": "Aman"; "B2": "Roshni"; "B3": "Kritika"; "B4": "Mansi"; "B5": "Dimple"]
not getting how to loop it.

Comment: it's not valid python code

Comment: What are `B1, B2, .., B6`? Are they `'B1', 'B2'` with strings?

Comment: yes it is string

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do something, but I first had to reformat your list1 and data into valid Python!

```
list1 = [{"B1": "Aman"}, {"B2": "Roshni"}, {"B3": "Utkarsh"}, {"B4": "Kritika"}, {"B5": "Mansi"}, {"B6": "Dimple"}]
data = 'B3'

key_list = [list(entry.keys())[0] for entry in list1]
if data in key_list:
    del_ind = key_list.index(data)
    num = int(data[1:])
    for i, key in enumerate(key_list):
        if (key_num := int(key[1:])) > num:
            list1[i] = {f'B{key_num - 1}': list1[i][key]}
    del list1[del_ind]
else:
    print(f'{data} is not in your list')

# [{'B1': 'Aman'}, {'B2': 'Roshni'}, {'B3': 'Kritika'}, {'B4': 'Mansi'}, {'B5': 'Dimple'}]
```